# Create and delete log files in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I am creating log file for check either block of code is executing or not.

I am using following code for create log file

```
Mage::log('Inside block',null,"filename.log",true);
```

Its working perfectly and creating log file inside `var/log/` folder.

Now I have doubt about I can delete that log file using any code.

I need to delete the log file programmatically,can I ?

> Note : I want to delete only file not folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log' . DS . 'filename.log';
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->rm($path);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible via PHP's unlink function.

Example:

```
unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . "log" . DS . "filename.log");
```

Comment: Its working,but I asked any possiblity in magento way. 'sv3n' gave solution in magento way. I upvoted to your answer for your quick response.Thanks @Ricky Odin Matthews